# "Permission denied" when uploading files

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm trying to implement a simple script for file uploading. Here's the code:

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
$extension = strtolower(end(explode(".", $_FILES["fotocarnet"]["name"])));
if ((($_FILES["fotocarnet"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["fotocarnet"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["fotocarnet"]["type"] == "image/png")
|| ($_FILES["fotocarnet"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
&& ($_FILES["fotocarnet"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["fotocarnet"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["fotocarnet"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["fotocarnet"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["fotocarnet"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["fotocarnet"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["fotocarnet"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("nada/" . $_FILES["fotocarnet"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["fotocarnet"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fotocarnet"]["tmp_name"],
      'nada/' . $_FILES["fotocarnet"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "nada/" . $_FILES["fotocarnet"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file: ".$extension;
  }
?>
```

Here's the output

```
Upload: MARTÍNEZGARCÍAGIANCKO.JPG
Type: image/jpeg
Size: 3.6513671875 kB
Temp file: C:\Windows\Temp\phpE21C.tmp

Warning: : failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Italia\IngSubirFotoCarnetIns_Italia.php on line 29

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Italia\IngSubirFotoCarnetIns_Italia.php on line 29
Stored in: nada/MARTÍNEZGARCÍAGIANCKO.JPG
```

And in php.ini I have this:

```
upload_tmp_dir=C:\inetpub\wwwroot\upload
```

The catch: I've already set the permissions to `C:\Windows\Temp\`, to `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\upload` and to `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Italia\nada`. Not only that but I already tried with `ini_set()`. Worst, I even upgraded PHP to 5.4 and it's still not working (and in every case I get the exact same error with the exact same upload folder, in `Windows\Temp`).

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What permissions did you set, exactly?

Comment: Full control to `IIS_IUSRS`

Comment: Mike: I tried changing `upload_tmp_dir` to `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\upload` in runtime and it still saves the file in `Windows\Temp`.

Comment: has there been any resolution to this???

Comment: Yes, let me answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was pretty simple: I had to set full permissions to `USERS` instead.